# Using itertools to get a large number of unique permutations

Tags: python, python-3.x, permutation

I have a question as such: How many ways are there to change order of letters in "avocadojuice" so that the vowel comes up first, for example "ovacadojuice" is a solution? The starting point - "avocadojuice" is also a solution.
I know that `itertools.permutations` can do things like this, but if the word is too long it pops up a memory error. Is there a way to prevent this, or maybe there is another built in module, which can solve this? Thank you in advance!
P.S. I know how to turn permutation tuples into strings.

Comment: Your question asks you to *count* the number of combinations, not to actually *produce* those. It is a math problem, not a programming problem.

Comment: Would it not be quicker and easier if I use python?

Comment: You mean, "use itertools in Python to generate all combinations"? Easier, perhaps, if you want to avoid thinking up a math solution. Definitely not quicker, as you already discovered you run out of memory, and even if you avoid that generating all those combinations takes *time*. A math approach would simply calculate the number each time. That'll be far, far, *far* quicker to produce.

Comment: Why not use generators for this purpose? Do you mean permutation or calculating the number of ways a sequence can be re-arranged?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a case were brute-forcing the problem probably isn't feasible. You need to compute the number of *unique permutations* of *n* elements, accounting for the fact that some elements are repeated.

There is a mathematical formula for this, and [some](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1759845/78023) [excellent](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1203251/78023) [answers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20238/6-letter-permutations-in-mississippi?rq=1) on other stack exchange sites.

Only `a` and `o` are repeated, so the number of unique permuations of `avocadojuice` is

```
(12!) / (2!2!)
```

or `119750400`

At roughly `45 bytes` per 12-character string (on my machine at least), that's over 5 gigs of memory just to store the nearly 120 million permutations!  You can see why brute forcing this isn't such a great idea.

You have one extra requirement in your problem though, which is that the permutations must start with a vowel.  Given that there are only 5 vowels, you should be able to calculate the possible permutations with each of the given vowels as the first character.

```
(11! / 2!) +      # a (only o is repeated)
(11! / (2!2!)) +  # e
(11! / (2!2!)) +  # i
(11! / 2!) +      # o (only a is repeated)
(11! / (2!2!)) +  # u
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is excellent. Even better, since you provided examples!

Comment: By the way, do you know how to write 11! in python? I hope it is not just 1*2*3*4*5*6*7*8*9*10*11.

Comment: `import math; math.factorial(11)`

Comment: write it as 39916800